# phpmyadmin Optimize Table Read Timeout

Tags: mysql, optimization, phpmyadmin

A table has 15,000 rows and the **Space usage** is as follows:

```
Type     |   Usage
Data     |   437.4 KiB
Index    |   157.0 KiB
Overhead |   7,000 B (this is in red)
Effective|   587.6 KiB
Total    |   594.4 KiB
```

When I click **Optimize table** it displays a read timeout after around 10 minutes.  Any ideas how I can get out of this rut?

```
ERROR

The requested URL could not be retrieved

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: Myaddress/phpmyadmin/sql.php?

Read Timeout

The system returned: [No Error]

A Timeout occurred while waiting to read data from the network. The network or server may be down or congested. Please retry your request.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do was not use a web interface like PHPMYADMIN rather I had to download **MySQL Workbench** and use these command lines in the query:

```
use databasename;
check table tablename;
repair table tablename;
optimize table tablename;

CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER
```