# Preventing MySql from closing the connection

Tags: mysql

On a server, I login on to MySql and try executing "optimize table" on a table that has 10GB in size. After about 20 minutes of execution, MySql decides to close the connection and my command fails with error message saying that connection was open for too long and closed during execution.
Why?
Connection to the DB is local (MySql server is local), "interactive_timeout" is set to about 8 hours, as well as "wait_timeout". I want to run that command and keep it running (with underlying connection open) for as long as necessary. During that time all other connections are closed and server isn't really used. MySql version in question is 5.6.31

Comment: Possible duplicate of [phpmyadmin Optimize Table Read Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428415/phpmyadmin-optimize-table-read-timeout)

Comment: From which client are you running that command?  From cli, from MySQL WorkBench, from .net console application, ...?

Comment: I'm running it from CLI